# UNNEST returns no rows for empty array

Tags: sql, arrays, presto, amazon-athena, unnest

I am using `unnest` for more flatten more than one array in Athena query. When the array has some records it returns the correct result. But when the second array is empty it is returning no records. Can someone please let me know how to do unnest to unnest more than one array in a single query?

The following query returns empty row.

```
WITH example AS (
 SELECT devop, devs 
 FROM

   UNNEST(ARRAY['Sharon', 'John', 'Bob', 'Sally']) AS t(devop),
     UNNEST(ARRAY[]) AS t(devs)
)
select array_join(array_agg(distinct example.devop),';'),array_join(array_agg(distinct example.devs),';') from example
```

The following query returns the correct result.

```
WITH example AS (
 SELECT devop, devs 
 FROM

   UNNEST(ARRAY['Sharon', 'John', 'Bob', 'Sally']) AS t(devop),
     UNNEST(ARRAY['a','b']) AS t(devs)
)
select array_join(array_agg(distinct example.devop),';'),array_join(array_agg(distinct example.devs),';') from example
```

When the second array is empty I want the following result

```
_col0                             _col1
----------------------------------------------
Sally;John;Bob;Sharon
```

Comment: Which result would you expect when the second array is empty?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `left join`:

```
WITH example AS (
      SELECT devop, devs 
      FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['Sharon', 'John', 'Bob', 'Sally']) AS t(devop) LEFT JOIN
           UNNEST(ARRAY[]) AS t(devs)
           ON 1=1
    )
. . .
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN UNNEST` is the proper answer, and this problem is exactly why we implemented it! Note that you need Presto 323 or newer, so in particular it does not work in Athena yet.

Comment: In Athena I get this error `SYNTAX_ERROR: line 4:12: UNNEST on other than the right side of CROSS JOIN is not supported` I tried the following command `WITH example AS (
      SELECT devop, devs 
      FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['Sharon', 'John', 'Bob', 'Sally']) AS t(devop) LEFT JOIN
           UNNEST(ARRAY[]) AS t(devs)
           ON 1=1)
    
select array_join(array_agg(distinct example.devop),';'),array_join(array_agg(distinct example.devs),';') from example`

Comment: Even Athena engine version 2 is based on Presto 0.217. So no way to do `LEFT JOIN UNNEST`. Any other workaround?

Comment: Athena engine version 3 supports this, although it requires `ON TRUE`

Answer (score 6):

Since `LEFT JOIN UNNEST` doesn't work on Athena Presto, you can cross-join on null values using the [`IF`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html?highlight=#if) and [`CARDINALITY`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html?highlight=cardinality#cardinality) like this:

```
WITH example AS (
  SELECT devop, devs 
  FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['Sharon', 'John', 'Bob', 'Sally']) AS t(devop) CROSS JOIN
       UNNEST(IF(CARDINALITY(ARRAY[])=0, ARRAY[NULL], ARRAY[]) AS t(devs)
)
```

This way, if the ARRAY[]/Column is empty (`CARDINALITY` checks the size of array), ARRAY[NULL] is returned and the row is not skipped.

(tested on Presto 0.217 / Athena engine version 2)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you want a `cross join` here. Instead, you could phrase this as:

```
select 
    array_join(
        array_agg(distinct unnest(array['Sharon', 'John', 'Bob', 'Sally'])),
        ';'
    ) devops,
    array_join(
        array_agg(distinct unnest(array[])),
        ';'
    ) devs
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work `INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Input type array(varchar(6)) not supported` in Athena

Comment: @somename: I gave a second attempt at this. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Try to `array_union` with a null array,

Below query will give you the desired result. Tested on `Athena engine version 1`.

```
WITH example AS (
 SELECT devop, devs 
 FROM

   UNNEST(ARRAY['Sharon', 'John', 'Bob', 'Sally']) AS t(devop),
     UNNEST(array_union(ARRAY[], ARRAY[null])) AS t(devs)
)
select array_join(array_agg(distinct example.devop),';'),array_join(array_agg(distinct example.devs),';') from example
```